Use different useSelect hooks without causing a change in hook order
I'm requesting different resources which are stored in a Store. For clarity I put it in a switch statement.

....

// for demonstration purpose.
switch (type){
    case 'foo':
        const data = useSelect( (select) => select(MY_STORE).getFoo(), []);
    break;

    case 'bar':
        const data = useSelect( (select) => select(MY_STORE).getFoo(), []);
    break;

    case 'zoo':
        const data = useSelect( (select) => select(MY_STORE).getZoo(), []);
    break;
}


....

The data is requested from the server so I don't need to fetch them all every time but instead only when it's actually needed.
The type can get changed with a user input but this can cause a "change in the order of Hooks called by..." error.
How can I use useSelect to fetch data from an endpoint and don't fetch all endpoints on the first render?
edit
Do I have to only have one useSelect?
const data = useSelect((select) => {
    case 'foo':
        return select(MY_STORE).getFoo();
    break;

    case 'bar':
        return select(MY_STORE).getFoo();
    break;

    case 'zoo':
        return select(MY_STORE).getZoo();
    break;
});

Edit 2
This from the console:
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useRef                     useRef
2. useContext                 useContext
3. useContext                 useContext
4. useMemo                    useMemo
5. useCallback                useCallback
6. useSyncExternalStore       useSyncExternalStore
7. useDebugValue              useDebugValue
8. undefined                  useRef
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Does this mean my problem is actually not coming from useSelect?

is useSelect a custom hook that you built, or is it a dependency that you are importing into your app?

It's actually from the WordPress data package: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/

Your edit is probably a good solution.  It also seems like the select method might be more appropriate to your situation.   The useSelect hook seems to be designed to work on page render, while select seems like it works on demand.  https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-data/#select

using select without the wrapper causes an undefined on the first render (as the data is not fetched yet). Does my 2nd edit helps more?

yeah, sorry I'm not familiar with wordpress and that api.  Your edit is the way to avoid the error with react hooks.  You can't conditionally call a hook, even if you're calling the same hook but in a switch statement.   Your edit calls the hook once but calls it with different arguments based on the switch statement. That's a correct use of hooks.
